# Use Nuke to load image into UICollectionViewListCell

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlistcell

`UICollectionViewListCell` is configured like so:

```
var configuration = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
configuration.text = "Foo"
configuration.image = UIImage(named: "foo")
configuration.imageProperties.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
cell.contentConfiguration = configuration
```

How can I use [Nuke](https://github.com/kean/Nuke) to load the image from a URL? With `UITableViewCell`, we can do:

```
Nuke.loadImage(with: url, into: cell.imageView)
```

But `UICollectionViewListCell` does not have an imageView.

Answer (score 0):

I did with kingfisher:

```
var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
let image = UIImageView()
        image.image = UIImage(named:"EmptyProfile.png")
        if let url = URL(string: user.avatarURL) {
            image.load(url: url)
        }
content.image = image.image

cell.contentConfiguration = content
```

--

```
extension UIImageView {
    func load(url: URL) {
        self.kf.setImage(with: url)
    }
}
```